# How to pass embedded ruby code as ID parameter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

Notice the :id section :

```
<% form_tag session_path, :id => 'elm_id_<%=  @product.count %>',
        :class => 'elm_class', :style => 'elm_style' do -%>


   # My Codes goes here

<% end -%>
```

Here I want to append the product count with the default text 'elm_id' and  set the whole thing as ID. But above code does not work. :(

Answer (score 2):

You're already in Ruby ERB tags for the form, you don't need them again inside the string. You need to interpolate the string, thus:

```
<% form_tag session_path, :id => "elm_id_#{@product.count}", ...
```

Comment: You need a double-quoted string - `"elm_id_#{@product.count}"` - as the `#{}` won't be interpreted in a single-quoted string.